# create vertical lines in seekbar

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, android-seekbar

I'm trying to create something like this[image: this]. The problem is how to create vertical lines close to the seekbar. I tried the code given [here](http://www.bridgecrossing.co.uk/viewpost.php?post=80), but the seekbar line disappears. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I've done so far.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);



            //Get the width of the main view.
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point displaysize = new Point();
            display.getSize(displaysize);
            int width = displaysize.x;




            //set the seekbar maximum (Must be a even number, having a remainder will cause undersirable results)
            //this variable will also determine the number of points on the scale.
            int seekbarmax = 10;




            int seekbarpoints = (width/seekbarmax); //this will determine how many points on the scale there should be on the seekbar


            //find the seekbar in the view, and set some behaviour properties
            SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);


            //Set the seekbar to a max range of 10
            seekbar.setMax(seekbarmax);




            //Create a new bitmap that is the width of the screen
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            //A new canvas to draw on.
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


            //a new style of painting - colour and stoke thickness.
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); //Set the colour to red
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); //set the style
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1); //Stoke width


            Paint textpaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            textpaint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));// text color RGB
            textpaint.setTextSize(28);// text size




            int point = 0; //initiate the point variable


            //Start a for loop that will loop seekbarpoints number of times.
            for (int i = 0; i < seekbarpoints; i++  ){




                if ((i%2)==0) {
                    //short line
                    point = point  + seekbarpoints;
                    canvas.drawLine(point, 30, point, 0, paint);
                    //drawLine(startx,startx,endy,endy)

            }


            //Create a new Drawable
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);


            //Set the seekbar widgets background to the above drawable.
            seekbar.setProgressDrawable(d);





            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: for achieving that look, the easiest solution would be to create custom view that extends Seekbar and in onDraw you can draw steps that you need.

Comment: can you give me some code sample?

Comment: You have many examples here and on Internet. Here is good example for SeekBar with range https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar. You can try this library and customize it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the this for long time and only got an answer to draw the numbers. Thus I decided to do it myself. I took the solution having only the  steps and extended it by adding the logic for the intervals.

Please see the below image.

[image]

I then successfully created a seekbar with interval lables and vertical lines over seekbar. The above image is what I've achieved.

However there are few optimization in the padding which you can work on adjusting the dimensions.

Solution :

The `xml` file for the intervals:

**seekbar_with_intervals_labels**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewInterval"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="#707070"/>
```

`XML` for the Vertical deviders : **seekbar_vertical_lines**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewVerticalLine"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lines" />
```

Then the custom Seekbar class :

```
package com.example.abc.myapplication;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;

import com.example.abc.myapplication.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SeekbarWithIntervals extends LinearLayout {
    private RelativeLayout RelativeLayout = null;
    private SeekBar Seekbar = null;
    private RelativeLayout Divider = null;
    private View verticalLine = null;

    private int WidthMeasureSpec = 0;
    private int HeightMeasureSpec = 0;

    public SeekbarWithIntervals(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.seekbar_with_intervals, this);
    }

    private Activity getActivity() {
        return (Activity) getContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        verticalLine = new View(getActivity());
        verticalLine.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(2, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        verticalLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        if (changed) {
            alignIntervals();

            // We've changed the intervals layout, we need to refresh.
            RelativeLayout.measure(WidthMeasureSpec, HeightMeasureSpec);
            RelativeLayout.layout(RelativeLayout.getLeft(), RelativeLayout.getTop(), RelativeLayout.getRight(), RelativeLayout.getBottom());
        }
    }

    private void alignIntervals() {
        int widthOfSeekbarThumb = getSeekbarThumbWidth();
        int thumbOffset = widthOfSeekbarThumb / 2;

        int widthOfSeekbar = getSeekbar().getWidth();
        int firstIntervalWidth = getRelativeLayout().getChildAt(0).getWidth();
        int remainingPaddableWidth = widthOfSeekbar - firstIntervalWidth - widthOfSeekbarThumb;

        int numberOfIntervals = getSeekbar().getMax();
        int maximumWidthOfEachInterval = remainingPaddableWidth / numberOfIntervals;

        alignFirstInterval(thumbOffset);
        alignIntervalsInBetween(maximumWidthOfEachInterval);
        alignLastInterval(thumbOffset, maximumWidthOfEachInterval);
    }

    private int getSeekbarThumbWidth() {
        return getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.seekbar_thumb_width);
    }

    private void alignFirstInterval(int offset) {
        TextView firstInterval = (TextView) getRelativeLayout().getChildAt(0);
        firstInterval.setPadding(offset - 10, 0, 0, 0);

        TextView firstLine = (TextView) getDivider().getChildAt(0);
        firstLine.setPadding(offset + 10, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private void alignIntervalsInBetween(int maximumWidthOfEachInterval) {
        int widthOfPreviousIntervalsText = 0;
        int widthOfPreviousLine = 0;

        // Don't align the first or last interval.
        for (int index = 1; index < (getRelativeLayout().getChildCount() - 1); index++) {
            TextView textViewInterval = (TextView) getRelativeLayout().getChildAt(index);
            int widthOfText = textViewInterval.getWidth();

            // This works out how much left padding is needed to center the current interval.
            //int leftPadding = Math.round(maximumWidthOfEachInterval - (widthOfText / 2) - (widthOfPreviousIntervalsText / 2) - (widthOfText / 2));
            int leftPadding = Math.round(maximumWidthOfEachInterval - (widthOfText / 2) - (widthOfPreviousIntervalsText / 2) - (widthOfText / index ) + index + 5 * 5);

            textViewInterval.setPadding(leftPadding, 0, 0, 0);

            widthOfPreviousIntervalsText = widthOfText;

            TextView textViewLine = (TextView) getDivider().getChildAt(index);
            int widthOfLine = textViewLine.getWidth();

            // This works out how much left padding is needed to center the current interval.
            leftPadding = (maximumWidthOfEachInterval + (index + (maximumWidthOfEachInterval / 10)) - (index * 4)); //Math.round(maximumWidthOfEachInterval + (widthOfLine ) + (widthOfPreviousLine ));
            //leftPadding = Math.round((maximumWidthOfEachInterval - (widthOfPreviousLine / index) - (widthOfPreviousLine / index) - (widthOfPreviousLine / index)) + 10);
            textViewLine.setPadding(leftPadding , 0, 0, 0);

            widthOfPreviousLine = widthOfLine;
        }
    }

    private void alignLastInterval(int offset, int maximumWidthOfEachInterval) {
        int lastIndex = getRelativeLayout().getChildCount() - 1;

        TextView lastInterval = (TextView) getRelativeLayout().getChildAt(lastIndex);
        int widthOfText = lastInterval.getWidth();

        int leftPadding = Math.round(maximumWidthOfEachInterval - widthOfText - offset);
        lastInterval.setPadding(leftPadding + 20, 0, 0, 0);

        TextView lastLine = (TextView) getDivider().getChildAt(lastIndex);
        leftPadding = Math.round(maximumWidthOfEachInterval - (widthOfText / 5) - (widthOfText / 5) - (widthOfText / 5 ) + 3 * 10);
        lastLine.setPadding(leftPadding , 0, 0, 0);

    }

    protected synchronized void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        WidthMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec;
        HeightMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec;

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return getSeekbar().getProgress();
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        getSeekbar().setProgress(progress);
    }

    public void setIntervals(List<String> intervals) {
        displayIntervals(intervals);
        getSeekbar().setMax(intervals.size() - 1);
    }

    private void displayIntervals(List<String> intervals) {
        int idOfPreviousInterval = 0;
        int idOfPreviousLine = 0;

        if (getRelativeLayout().getChildCount() == 0) {
            for (String interval : intervals) {
                TextView textViewInterval = createInterval(interval);
                alignTextViewToRightOfPreviousInterval(textViewInterval, idOfPreviousInterval);

                TextView textViewVerticaLine = createVerticalLine();
                alignTextViewToRightOfPreviousInterval(textViewVerticaLine, idOfPreviousLine);
                idOfPreviousLine = textViewVerticaLine.getId();

                idOfPreviousInterval = textViewInterval.getId();

                getRelativeLayout().addView(textViewInterval);
                getDivider().addView(textViewVerticaLine);

            }
        }
    }

    private TextView createInterval(String interval) {
        View textBoxView = (View) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.seekbar_with_intervals_labels, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) textBoxView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewInterval);

        textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        textView.setText(interval);

        return textView;
    }

    private TextView createVerticalLine() {
        View textBoxView = (View) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.seekbar_vertical_lines, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) textBoxView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewVerticalLine);

        textView.setId(View.generateViewId());

        return textView;
    }


    private void alignTextViewToRightOfPreviousInterval(TextView textView, int idOfPreviousInterval) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (idOfPreviousInterval > 0) {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idOfPreviousInterval);
        }

        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener) {
        getSeekbar().setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);
    }

    private RelativeLayout getRelativeLayout() {
        if (RelativeLayout == null) {
            RelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.intervals);
        }

        return RelativeLayout;
    }

    private SeekBar getSeekbar() {
        if (Seekbar == null) {
            Seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        }

        return Seekbar;
    }

    private RelativeLayout getDivider() {

        if (Divider == null) {
            Divider = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_divider);
        }

        return Divider;
    }
}
```

Then the **MainActivity** where we dynamically add the intervals.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SeekbarWithIntervals SeekbarWithIntervals = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> seekbarIntervals = getIntervals();
        getSeekbarWithIntervals().setIntervals(seekbarIntervals);
    }

    private List<String> getIntervals() {
        return new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("45");
            add("55");
            add("65");
            add("75");
            add("85");
            add("95");
        }};
    }

    private SeekbarWithIntervals getSeekbarWithIntervals() {
        if (SeekbarWithIntervals == null) {
            SeekbarWithIntervals = (SeekbarWithIntervals) findViewById(R.id.seekbarWithIntervals);
        }

        return SeekbarWithIntervals;
    }
}
```

You can put the padding bottom of the divider so as to push it upwards like in your image.

Note : You can also have a single layout defining the divider and the number layout.

Comment: @Ashary P What is in seekbar_with_intervals

Answer (score 0):

You will need two PNG drawables one for `background` and one for `progress`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable_frost" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable_frost_progress" />

</layer-list>
```